# Passing a xml child node by reference

Tags: xml, perl, reference

i'm trying to pass an xml child node by reference in PERL but I keep receiving a 
"Not a HASH reference at" error

```
my $global_XMLData = $xml->XMLin($response->content(), ForceArray => ['Parent']);

for my $child(@{$global_XMLData->{Parent})
{
        parseXML(\$child);
}

sub parseXML
{

    my $child= shift;
    $global_bu{bu_id} = $child->{theAttribute};

    # There's about 20-30 more attributes to get, 
    # but for this example, there's only one
}
```

Now If i pass it by value it works just fine and I do get the data but every time i try to pass it by reference I keep receiving the error. Any help? I just don't want the data to be a copy since it's a rather large xml child node.

Comment: I really think your life would be improved by not using XML::Simple.  I wrote [this tutorial](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/) to help people get started with XML::LibXML which is much less confusing than XML::Simple.

Answer (score 1):

`$child` is already a reference. You can see this if you call `print $child` or `print ref($child)` before the `parseXML()` call. You should be fine if you just call `parseXML($child)`.

`\$child`, which is getting passed to the `parseXML` function, is necessarily a scalar reference, and it doesn't make sense to use it as a hash reference as you do inside `parseXML()`.